# Connection timeout calling open api

Tags: api, openfda, download

We are using below APIs to fetch the data using python but it continues to give us connection timeout and connection forcibly refused error:

1. https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json
2. https://api.fda.gov/download.json

Kindly help

Thanks,
Shailendra J

Answer (score 0):

These two endpoints appear to be functioning normally and no outages have been recorded on the openFDA side. You can check the status of openFDA endpoints on this page: https://open.fda.gov/about/status/

Answer (score 0):

Normally with med device data it's a date-time error with server communication. Specifically, your nested dates.

If you included what the error code was you might get a more succinct answer, but its not always possible to do that, So...

Trouble-shoot.

1. Is your data "manifest" (xml) properly formatted?
2. Are there any problematic characters you might be ignoring?
3. How large is the file? and does that matter based on how frequently
   you'll get them?

No one can help you with this just based on the endpoints you provided unless they have additional information. AND, because it's a cottage IT standard, there's more nuance to it than expected. Provide more information and you will get help.